# Does React.createElement always call a constructor?

Tags: reactjs

I have a class PexesoCard and a class Content which look like this:

```
const e = React.createElement;

class PexesoCard extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.value = this.props.value;
  this.onClick = this.props.handleOnClick;
  this.state = { state: 'unturned' };
}

componentDidMount() {
  var self = this;
  ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener("click", function() { self.onClick(self) } );
}

render() {
  return e(
    'div',
    { className: 'pexeso-card' },
      this.state.state == 'turned' ?
        e(Content, {value: this.value}) :
      this.state.state == 'unturned' ?
        e(Content, {value: 'unturned'}) :
        e(Content, {value: 'removed'})
  )
}} 

class Content extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.value = this.props.value;
}

render() {
  return React.createElement(
    'div',
    { className: 'content' },
    `${this.value}`
  )
}}
```

Although the class Content seems useless here, it is a preparation for more complex content of pexeso cards I would like to create later.

In the function PexesoCard.props.handleOnClick the state of PexesoCard is changed to 'turned'. Then in a debugger I see that function render() is called correctly with state = 'turned' and e(Content, {value: this.value}) is called. However then the render function of Content is called where this.value = 'unturned' and this.props.value = the correct value I want to display. I don't understand how this is possible. Shouldn't new instance of the class Content be created in React.createComponent? Or what did I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.createElement`(or it's JSX syntax version of`<Content propq={value1} />`) does not re-create elements unconditionally. If it did, we all would have 2 bad outcomes: losing internal state(sure, not every component is destined to have it) and much lower performance.

Instead, if React sees:

1. Constructor is referentially the same
2. There is no different value for special `key` prop

Then React reuses existing element of the same type/constructor.
On the component's class level it means instead of `constructor` + `componentDidMount` + `render` there will be called `componentDidUpdate` + `render`.

All the process has name of "reconciliation" if you want to read more details.

Comment: Thank you for an explanation, it was useful.

Comment: glad to help. btw, I don't know why you use [`createElement` API over JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) syntax(Preact?), but anyway I think for asking at StackOverflow it might be more effective to ask with JSX. Otherwise you may cut off some people who could answer but see `.createElement` in the wild for a first time.

Comment: I've started with React last month so I am still in a learning process. I haven't thought about JSX because this createElement syntax seemed to me easy to write and easy to read, but thank you for this suggestion, I will definitely look at it.